# Create android keystory/ private key command line

Tags: android, cordova, android-build

I have built my application with cordova command line.
Now I understand that in order to release I need to get Keystore and private key.
In android documentation I see that I need to do it on Android studio.
http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html
But if I get it correctly I will need to build the project with android studio and not in command line.
But I thought that the recommended form was to work with command line in cordova.

Is it possible to create keystore/ private key in command line?
If not is it possible to open a project that I have built in codova with Adnroid studio, create 
keystore/ private key and then build it again in cordova.

Also do you need to create a different keystore/ private key for each project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check [**this section**](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#signing-manually).
*"You do not need Android Studio or the ADT plugin for Eclipse to sign your app"*

### How to sign your app manually.

#### Generate a private key using keytool. For example:

```
$ keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore
-alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

This example prompts you for passwords for the keystore and key, and to provide the Distinguished Name fields for your key. It then generates the keystore as a file called my-release-key.keystore. The keystore contains a single key, valid for 10000 days. The alias is a name that you will use later when signing your app.

#### Compile your app in release mode to obtain an unsigned APK.

#### Sign your app with your private key using jarsigner:

```
$ jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1
-keystore my-release-key.keystore my_application.apk alias_name
```

This example prompts you for passwords for the keystore and key. It then modifies the APK in-place to sign it. Note that you can sign an APK multiple times with different keys.

#### Verify that your APK is signed. For example:

```
$ jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs my_application.apk
```

#### Align the final APK package using zipalign.

```
$ zipalign -v 4 your_project_name-unaligned.apk your_project_name.apk
```

zipalign ensures that all uncompressed data starts with a particular byte alignment relative to the start of the file, which reduces the amount of RAM consumed by an app.

Comment: Thanks. It works. I haven't noticed it since it was at the end of the page.

Comment: I don't get it.
jarsigner: Certificate chain not found for: alias_name.  alias_name must reference a valid KeyStore key entry containing a private key and corresponding public key certificate chain.

Comment: somehow the alias is mykey

Comment: but now jarsigner error: java.security.SignatureException: private key algorithm is not compatible with signature algorithm